# How to make Selenium click the right radio button based on text in table?

Tags: selenium, radio-button, bdd, selenium-webdriver

Okay, given the following situation:

```
<tr>
   <td> input="the wrong radio button" </td>
   <td> the wrong title </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> input="the right radio button" </td>
   <td> the right title </td>
</tr>
```

I have "the right title" already stored in a variable. How can I make Selenium click the right radio button?

The radios have dynamic id´s (e.g. foo_bar_4711) that aren ´t directly related with the title.

I would need something like "click the radio button in the tr that containts a td having the text you are looking for".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an XPath locator that differentiates between the two buttons.  Something like `xpath=tr[td[.='the right title']]//input`.  In English, that means "*the input button contained within the table row that contains a table cell who's text is 'the right title'*".

Comment: Thank you aswell, I like the translation into english ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Use xpath, something like `//td[contains(text(),'the right title')]/../td[1]`. The key is to use `..` to go back up one level in the tree.