# How to select a table record depending on table element using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

A table has 2 or more rows (depending on previous action) and the contents are not ordered.  One of the column has unique elements.  I need to select the row depending on the unique element using selenium webdriver (java). I am passing the locators using an excel sheet.

For eg, I have the following kind of table:

---

### Select         Name     Id

Radio_button   ABC        Id1

Radio_button   ABC        Id2

Suppose for the above table, the order of the rows are not same all the time and depending on id value, I need to select the correct radio button.  How do I identify the correct radio button depending on the id value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [xpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx) for finding your element:

```
//tr[*[@id='id1']]//input
```

This is a locator for Radio_button that is in the same row as id1.
If you provide your html code of the table, the answer will be more precisely, but the general idea is clear, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Though the selenium doesnt give any error for the xpath (verifyVisible), which you had mentioned , am not able to click/check on that particular radio button.

It identifies only the first radio button and checks on that.

Comment: Problem got solved with the xpath //td[contains(text(),'id1')]/../td[1]/input

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615378/how-to-make-selenium-click-the-right-radio-button-based-on-text-in-table

Comment: Of course it will identify not your actual radiobutton as you didn't provide any code. In my xpath you should just replace `@id` with `text()` and it will work too: `//tr[*[contains(text(),'id1')]]//input`. Also use `add comment` instead of `Add another answer` if you want to reply on somebody's answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! This path is also working fine.  Ok..sure! I will comment from now on when I want to reply.